# vtkTextActor doesn't work

Tags: python, vtk

I'm trying to run [this example VTK code](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Python/GeometricObjects/TextActor/), but it doesn't work as intended. I get a window with a green background but not text.

I'm running Windows 7, VTK 6.3 with Python 2.7.14, which I installed using Anaconda.

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that VTK 6 doesn't have text features. I had to upgrade to VTK 8. I thought I was running the most recent version of VTK, but in fact Anaconda gave me 6 because 8 isn't compatible with Python 2.7 (so I also had to install Python 3).

Upgrading to VTK 8 solves the problem.